# InterfaceError: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pandas

When I'm trying to connect to the **MySql** Database server in **Python** on *Google Cloud Platform*, I'm getting the error. The following is the actual code.

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'xxxxxx', password='xxxxxx',
                              host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xx',
                              database='xxxxxxxxx')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cnx.close()
if cur and con:                        
    cur.close() 
    con.close()
sql1 = "SELECT * FROM ms_trackevaluation_15_16.ms_skill"
cursor.execute(sql1)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
df1 = pd.read_sql(sql1, cnx)
```

The following is the error :

```
InterfaceError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-30094be976fb> in <module>()
      4 cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'xxxxx', password='xxxxx',
      5                               host='173.194.104.33',
----> 6                               database='xxxxx')
      7 cursor = cnx.cursor()
      8 cnx.close()

    /home/scrollstech_shravankumar/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py in connect(*args, **kwargs)
        177         return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
        178     else:
    --> 179         return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
        180 Connect = connect  # pylint: disable=C0103
        181 
    
    /home/scrollstech_shravankumar/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
         93 
         94         if len(kwargs) > 0:
    ---> 95             self.connect(**kwargs)
         96 
         97     def _do_handshake(self):
    
    /home/scrollstech_shravankumar/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py in connect(self, **kwargs)
        714 
        715         self.disconnect()
    --> 716         self._open_connection()
        717         self._post_connection()
        718 
    
    /home/scrollstech_shravankumar/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py in _open_connection(self)
        205         self._socket = self._get_connection()
        206         self._socket.open_connection()
    --> 207         self._do_handshake()
        208         self._do_auth(self._user, self._password,
        209                       self._database, self._client_flags, self._charset_id,
    
    /home/scrollstech_shravankumar/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py in _do_handshake(self)
         97     def _do_handshake(self):
         98         """Get the handshake from the MySQL server"""
    ---> 99         packet = self._socket.recv()
        100         if packet[4] == 255:
        101             raise errors.get_exception(packet)
    
    /home/scrollstech_shravankumar/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py in recv_plain(self)
        241                 chunk = self.sock.recv(4 - packet_len)
        242                 if not chunk:
    --> 243                     raise errors.InterfaceError(errno=2013)
        244                 packet += chunk
        245                 packet_len = len(packet)
    
    InterfaceError: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Can anyone explain what's wrong with this code and why I'm getting this error.  And please explain how can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: Can you check if your mysql server is having port exposed for communication. By default its 3306 unless you have modified it. Seems to be network issue only.

Comment: I haven't modified it. The port number is same as the root server and the server I'm using right now.

Comment: then look for firewall in you server, maybe thats restricting communication on default port.

Answer (score 1):

From [Mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-lost-connection.html), Here is the reason for that issue.

> Usually it indicates network connectivity trouble and you should check
> the condition of your network if this error occurs frequently. If the
> error message includes “during query,” this is probably the case you
> are experiencing.

The workaround to this as they stated is to :

> increase `net_read_timeout` from its default of 30 seconds to 60
> seconds or longer

How to do that in python:

If you are using SQLAlchemy use add the timeout parameter to the connection engine function and you will be good to go.

Here is an example

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(self.writer_url, 
                       connect_args={'connect_timeout': 120},
                       pool_pre_ping=True)
```

The `pool_pre_ping` was grabed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61870014/4683950) .

Answer (score 0):

Refer following form :
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-lost-connection.html

B.5.2.3 Lost connection to MySQL server

There are three likely causes for this error message.

Usually it indicates network connectivity trouble and you should check the condition of your network if this error occurs frequently. If the error message includes “during query,” this is probably the case you are experiencing.

Sometimes the “during query” form happens when millions of rows are being sent as part of one or more queries. If you know that this is happening, you should try increasing net_read_timeout from its default of 30 seconds to 60 seconds or longer, sufficient for the data transfer to complete.

More rarely, it can happen when the client is attempting the initial connection to the server. In this case, if your connect_timeout value is set to only a few seconds, you may be able to resolve the problem by increasing it to ten seconds, perhaps more if you have a very long distance or slow connection. You can determine whether you are experiencing this more uncommon cause by using SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Aborted_connects'. It will increase by one for each initial connection attempt that the server aborts. You may see “reading authorization packet” as part of the error message; if so, that also suggests that this is the solution that you need.

If the cause is none of those just described, you may be experiencing a problem with BLOB values that are larger than max_allowed_packet, which can cause this error with some clients. Sometime you may see an ER_NET_PACKET_TOO_LARGE error, and that confirms that you need to increase max_allowed_packet.

Please try increasing connection timeout using:

```
`cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'shravan2018', password='password',
                              host='173.194.104.33',
                              database='ms_trackevaluation_15_16',
                              connect_timeout=1000 ,
                              wait_timeout=28800 ,
                              interactive_timeout=28800 )`
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I followed your steps accordingly but I'm getting this error, " AttributeError: Unsupported argument 'interactive_timeout' "

Comment: Sorry.
mysql.connector.connect(*args,**kwargs) does not support 'wait_timeout' and 'interactive_timeout' try by removing these two arguments.

Comment: sorry, again getting the same error " InterfaceError: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query ".